# transform: translateX Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, transform

I am trying to create a search bar that slides in when a button is clicked. I am using translateX(-100%) to position it off screen. However when I do this it adds a horizontal scroll to the page allowing you to scroll right and see the hidden search bar. I have tried a combination of position absolute on the search-bar and overflow-x: hidden on the header div.

See it action here: http://www.cqwebdesign.co.uk/saverplaces%202.0/TEST/index.html

Please view it on small screen as its built for mobile screens.

Thanks

Comment: `overflow: hidden` to `.inner-wrapper` anyway you should insert the code even on the question in order to prevent broken links

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly doing that also prevents you from being able to scroll vertically. I tried adding overflow-x: hidden; and it adds to scroll bars

Comment: then give the header an higher height and apply the overflow to that element